# Got error on Large Image Size (1600*2560) png format?

Tags: cocos2d-android

I got an error on Large Image size is about 1600*2560. **LogCat Detail is below :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCTextureCache$2.load(CCTextureCache.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.opengl.CCTexture2D.setLoader(CCTexture2D.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCTextureCache.createTextureFromFilePath(CCTextureCache.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCTextureCache.addImage(CCTextureCache.java:67)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite.<init>(CCSprite.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(2451): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite.sprite(CCSprite.java:267)
```

What is the solution for this ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html check the link and this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: perhaps the device's texture limit is 2048x2048, have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to decode your file, you have to specify the [Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html), such as image width, height, color format, sample size. Then you will not run out of your memory.